# Data Transfer of point on line using the anchor point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, select, anchor-point

Can I a line feature, the anchor point touches a point feature transferred the field value, even when the point touches another line(s)?

How does this work?

[image]

Comment: @Aaron, thanks for your commitment.
I would like to give a river which is available as a line object, the value of the Gazetteer (shown as a dot). The anchor point touches or is approaching at the point of the Gazetteer point. The problem is that the point also lying on another river.

Comment: What do you mean by "Anchor Point", are you talking about the black squares in your image? If so these are typically referred to as nodes. If the red point is exactly at the tributary junction then you cannot attach the field information to your target line without using more information. Your red dot must have more information like source or catchment ID to allow you to assign the information to the correct tributary.